# remove space between display:table-cell

Tags: html, css

I have a div that is `display:table;` - inside that div there are two `display:table-cell`.

one table-cell is a span holding and img,and the other is span holding text,

for some reason there is a space between the two `display:table-cell` that I don't want.

how can I made the table-cells be one next to each other?

here is my html:

```
<div class="statusCommentUser">
    <span><img src="/Content/Images/contactDemo_small_image.png" class="SmallUserImg"></span>
    <span>Sounds great, man!</span>
 </div>
```

here is my css:

```
.statusCommentUser {
    width:450px;
    height:50px;
    display:table;
}

.statusCommentUser span {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle; 
}
```

Comment: Not sure what your asking. The cells are next to each other.

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you assign css rule `display:table-cell` to any element, it behaves as any `td` element of some table. So, in that case, it auto adjusts itself according to the parent width and the number of other tds in the same row, only when, you don't specify a width to this td.

That's why both your span cum `TDs` are taking that width.
simply assign a width to the first one, it should solve your problem.

i.e. try adding this class

```
.statusCommentUser span:first-child{
    width:50px;
}
```

see the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/34FLx/2/)

Moreover, if all that you want is to position your image span and text span horizontally aligned, you can do it through many other ways i.e. change your css classes to this:

```
.statusCommentUser {
    width:450px;
    height:50px;
 }
.statusCommentUser span {
  float:left;
 }
.statusCommentUser span:last-child{
    position:relative;
    top:40px;
}
```

see this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/34FLx/6/)

Answer (score 0):

**[See Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Eu4mk/)**

Just add class to the `span` which contains your image and then set the `width`

HTML

```
<div class="statusCommentUser">
    <span class="user"><img src="http://placehold.it/30x30/" class="SmallUserImg"></span>
    <span>Sounds great, man!</span>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
span.user {
    width: 35px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `div` is acting like a table, try adding this to `.statusCommentUser`:

```
border-collapse: collapse;
```

This CSS is used to remove the spacing between cells in a table.

Comment: this css is not used to remove spacing between cells, it is used to merge the individual borders of different cells in a table. -1

Comment: Yes, merge borders, in other words: remove the spacing between borders, i.e. remove spacing between cells. Even if the cells don't have any border.

Answer (score 0):

The space comes from the newline and indentation between the two `<span>`s.

Try this:

```
<span><img width="100" height="100" class="SmallUserImg"></span><span>Sounds great, man!</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
.statusCommentUser img
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```

Your image will become the total size of your cell. Also your image has to be floated to be positioned in the cell (OP example the image is not in the middle of the cell).

To prevent stretching of the image, you can make a static width of the image span. Or you can make the cell adjust automatically based on the image size. However you would have to remove the static width of your div tabel.

*Manish Mishra's image used for dummy image ^^*

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L6mn7/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem and was able to resolve by adding the property in  display:table-cell element

```
border-spacing: 0;
```

Hope it solves for those still looking